# Having problems passing a list to other .js file using localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, local-storage

Having problems passing a list to other .js file using localStorage

I was trying to push the info to the list named as 'data' and store it in local storage to use the data in other .js file

I also include how I call in other .js file and use it in a class component
below but the data seems is not working or imported at thhe other .js file

```
//Trying to push the info to the list named as 'data' and store it in local storage to use the data in other .js file

renderBoxContent = () => {

  let total = 0;
  let Total = 0;
  let itemList = [];
  let  data = [];

  this.state.availableItems.map((items)=> {

      if(items.purchase > 0){
       Total += items.price*items.purchase;
       total = items.price*items.purchase;
       console.log(items.purchase);
       console.log(total);
        data.push(
          {
            key: items.name,
            name: items.name,
            src: items.image,
            singlePrice: items.price.toFixed(2),
            purchase: items.purchase,
            totalItemPrice: total.toFixed(2),
          }
        )
      }
  })

  //dataexported = data;

  localStorage.setItem("purchase-data",JSON.stringify(data));

  itemList.push(  <Table defaultExpandAllRows={false} locale={{emptyText: 'Empty Cart'}} style={{background: '#ffffff'}} pagination={false} columns={column} dataSource={data} size="small" />)
  itemList.push( <h3 style={{paddingLeft:15,paddingTop:20}}>    Total     {Total.toFixed(2)}</h3>)
  return itemList;
 }




//This is how I call in other .js file and use it in a class component
//But the data seems is not working or imported at thhe other .js file

let purchaseData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("purchase-data"));

export default class Favourites extends Component{

    renderCheckOut = () => {

        purchaseData.map((individual) => {

            return( 

        some codes here.... 
                )

        }


        render(){
            return(
            some codes here....
            )
        }
    }
```

it should return the components inside the map function

Comment: did you linked the js file ?

Comment: Sorry not understand what you mean by linked js file, can you show me some codes examples, its my first time hearing this

Comment: Does a get just after the set give positive results?

Comment: @NgJingXuan, I was taling something like that: `<script src="file1.js"></script>` or importing the object. But I am not sure as if you have added tag of reactJs and how it works for that.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage is usually accessible across your application. 
Please refer this demo https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-wildflower-50c6b?fontsize=14

In the above demo when you open `/` route the data is getting set into the localStorage and later when you open the `/about` route the same data is fetched from the localStorage and displayed in the HTML.

If your JS file is in same application accessing **localStorage** data should not be a problem looking at the above example.